# Conditionally forwarding incoming mail to a different address

Tags: email, gmail, g-suite, procmail

I have a task at hand that would involve grabbing incoming mail from an IMAPS server (Google Workspace), and then redirecting it to another address (for ingesting attachments from emails).

Sadly, I cannot use the built-in Gmail forwarding feature because it requires the recipient to accept a security code that they can't show up from their side.

Currently I have set up fetchmail+procmail+sSMTP for it. Fetchmail and Procmail worked fine, until I realized that I should only forward mail with attachments.

Currently, my `.procmailrc` is as follows:

```
:0
* ^Content-Disposition:.*attachment.*
* ^Content-Type:.*multipart/mixed.*
! where@to-forward.com
```

which doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Can you suggest either how to tune Procmail properly, or maybe another way to do it?

PS. procmail has been discontinued for over 20 years now! My god...

Comment: If it "doesn't work", it means the messages you are trying to match do not match these regular expressions. Can you show a sample message and perhaps ideally the Procmail log from when you tried to match it? Perhaps see also https://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Comment: Also, Procmail's original maintainer picked up where he left off, the latest release was about a year and a half ago. https://github.com/BuGlessRB/procmail